# Kubernetes : hostname regex failed

Tags: linux, docker, containers, kubernetes, hostname

Trying to run kubeadm init

```
[root@ts_kubernetes_setup ~]# kubeadm init
[kubeadm] WARNING: kubeadm is in alpha, please do not use it for production clusters.
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[preflight] WARNING: firewalld is active, please ensure ports [6443 9898 10250] are open or your cluster may not function correctly
[preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
        hostname "ts_kubernetes_setup.localdomain" must match the regex [a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)* (e.g. 'example.com')
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can skip pre-flight checks with `--skip-preflight-checks`
[root@ts_kubernetes_setup ~]#
```

Shows error on hostname. Can i run kudeadm on this machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a different name other than the hostname with the `--api-external-dns-names` as described in the [reference manual](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kubeadm/). E.g.:

```
kubeadm init --api-external-dns-names=kube.local
```

This should run just fine.

You could also change the hostname of your machine - you'll find plenty of ways to do that on [SO too](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=change%20hostname%20linux).

Comment: Also, I wanted to ask how to completely remove/uninstall kubernetes and its kubectl,kubeadm etc from Linux to start from scratch on the same machine?[My Linux knowledge is not so good.]